# How can I add pyqt5 buttons on top of each other?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to create a basic 25 key keyboard in  pyqt, I have laid out the 15 white keys but am struggling with how to add the 10 remaining black keys,

This is how I made my keys

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton
app = QApplication([])

top_win = QWidget() 
set_color(top_win, Qt.cyan)
top_win.setAutoFillBackground(True)
top_win.show() 
top_win.resize(1920,1080)
top_win.setWindowTitle("Synth-01") 
top_vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
top_win.setLayout(top_vlayout)

keyboard = QWidget()
keyboard.setMaximumWidth(1410)
top_vlayout.addWidget(keyboard)

keyboard_layout = QHBoxLayout()
keyboard.setAutoFillBackground(True)
keyboard.setLayout(keyboard_layout)

for i in range(15):
    name = "key_" + str(i)
    name = QPushButton()
    name.setMaximumWidth(94)
    name.setMaximumHeight(349)
    keyboard_layout.addWidget(name)
```

[image]

I now want to add the black keys inbetween like this
[image]

Comment: I think the buttons as you try can be complicated, I assume that when you press a key you want to do an action that is associated with an identifier as a string, if I am correct what those identifiers would be

Comment: I'm planning to play sounds when they're pressed, I should use better naming convention but for now I'd just like to know how to lay out the keys neatly, I'm thinking adding a seperate QWidget for the black keys but working out the positioning will be quite tedious

Comment: For that reason I say: What is this convention ?, I do not know anything about music but maybe it is something like "do", "re", etc., that is, what is the name of each key?

Comment: Oh sorry for that I meant that there was no particular naming convention other than` ["key_1", "key_2", "key_3"]` at the moment

Comment: For the music part, it would be something like C for Dó through G to Sol, then A, B for Lá and Sí. C D E F G A B. The black would be C#, D#, F#, G# and A#

Comment: Positioning the keys will be tedious, yeah. You can positionate relatively to the previews key, so C# relative to C, something like, on same Y, 2/3 X. I don't really know how the widgets will behave when you overlap they.

Comment: I just saw the letters on they keys now. LoL, just use the same letters as the keys, they are a milenar convention

Comment: See this. https://forum.qt.io/topic/15831/solved-how-to-overlap-widgets/5

Comment: In your case you should have a parent widget for keyboard, then you add all the keys then, position they, and lift the black ones by calling `raise_()` on it.

Comment: Thanks man that stacking widgets link was real handy ill update the p[ost once ive got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it is most preferable to use QGraphicsScene with QGraphicsItem, for this case I will use svg:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSvg 

class PianoKey(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, black=False, rect = QtCore.QRectF(), parent=None):
        super(PianoKey, self).__init__(rect, parent)
        self.m_pressed = False
        self.m_selectedBrush = QtGui.QBrush()
        self.m_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black) if black else QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white) 
        self.m_black = black

    def setPressedBrush(self, brush):
        self.m_selectedBrush = brush

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        rendered = QtSvg.QSvgRenderer("key.svg")
        black_pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1)
        gray_pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.gray), 1, 
            QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin)
        if self.m_pressed:
            if self.m_selectedBrush.style() != QtCore.Qt.NoBrush:
                painter.setBrush(self.m_selectedBrush)
            else:
                painter.setBrush(QtWidgets.QApplication.palette().highlight())
        else: 
            painter.setBrush(self.m_brush);
        painter.setPen(black_pen)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 15, 15, QtCore.Qt.RelativeSize)
        if self.m_black:
            rendered.render(painter, self.rect())
        else:
            points = [
                QtCore.QPointF(self.rect().left()+1.5, self.rect().bottom()-1),
                QtCore.QPointF(self.rect().right()-1, self.rect().bottom()-1),
                QtCore.QPointF(self.rect().right()-1, self.rect().top()+1)
            ]
            painter.setPen(gray_pen)
            painter.drawPolyline(QtGui.QPolygonF(points))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.m_pressed = True
        self.update()
        super(PianoKey, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        event.accept()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.m_pressed = False
        self.update()
        super(PianoKey, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

KEYWIDTH, KEYHEIGHT = 18, 72

class PianoKeyBoard(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, num_octaves=2,  parent=None):
        super(PianoKeyBoard, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initialize()
        self.m_numOctaves = num_octaves
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, KEYWIDTH * self.m_numOctaves * 7, KEYHEIGHT), self)
        self.setScene(scene)
        numkeys = self.m_numOctaves * 12

        for i in range(numkeys):
            octave = i//12*7
            j = i % 12
            if j >= 5: j += 1
            if j % 2 == 0:
                x = (octave + j/2)*KEYWIDTH
                key = PianoKey(rect=QtCore.QRectF(x, 0, KEYWIDTH, KEYHEIGHT), black=False)
            else:
                x = (octave + j//2) * KEYWIDTH  + KEYWIDTH * 6//10 + 1
                key = PianoKey(rect=QtCore.QRectF(x, 0, KEYWIDTH * 8//10 - 1, KEYHEIGHT * 6//10 ), black=True)
                key.setZValue(1)
            key.setPressedBrush(QtWidgets.QApplication.palette().highlight())
            self.scene().addItem(key)

    def initialize(self):
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_InputMethodEnabled, False)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setCacheMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setViewportUpdateMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.MinimalViewportUpdate)
        self.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing|
            QtGui.QPainter.TextAntialiasing | 
            QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        self.setOptimizationFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontClipPainter, True)
        self.setOptimizationFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontSavePainterState, True)
        self.setOptimizationFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontAdjustForAntialiasing, True)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtWidgets.QApplication.palette().base())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(PianoKeyBoard, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.fitInView(self.scene().sceneRect(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.mapFromScene(self.sceneRect()).boundingRect().size()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Piano Keyboard", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter))
    lay.addWidget(PianoKeyBoard())
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

The complete code + key.svg can be found on this [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55366046)

Comment: Oh you beauty! Thanks very much ill give this a go ASAP